# Is there a gui fuzzy finder like rofi?

Tags: command-line

[Rofi](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi) is a fuzzy searcher for linux (select one entry from a set of entries quickly by typing a substring). [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) is a similar tool for the shell.

This is useful for quickly producing hacky GUI interfaces.

Is there a similar way to easily select one of several strings with a gui from the command-line in mac?

## Example of what rofi is useful for

Searching and playing audio files from a known location.

```
cd music
ls | rofi | xargs vlc
```

You might bind this to a key.

The key point is that you have complete programmatic control over the input to the fuzzy finder and how the output is used.

Comment: even if Spotlight does a lot of what you seem to describe, I am used to [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com/), but I don't understand if you are looking for an app or for a library to include in other projects - and btw both Spotlight and Quicksilver can be extended with plugins

Comment: Another one would be [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/). It can also be extended with "Workflows", but that feature requires a powerpack license that costs moneys.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmm, how much control does one have over the input and actions of quicksilver and alfred. I kind of want something I can use for hacky scripting where I can completely control input and output from my script. Kind of a like a combobox popup that takes you 10 seconds to code.

Comment: As someone who just writes barely working applescripts with Alfred, I can't really say. I've seen many Workflows where people have done cool stuff, but I wouldn't know about the process. There's [Packal](http://www.packal.org/workflow-search), which has tons of Workflows people have made (Some more can be found I  github/google). Sadly Alfred doesn't have a trial for the power pack. I couldn't find good videos on custom Workflows though you should still check those out. They should at least show you how that interface works a little bit.

Comment: These are the best videos I could find. They show how Workflows are created. This first one is sort of basic Workflow with an argument https://youtu.be/OtazipiwMkQ and this second hows shows how script filters can be made  https://youtu.be/JMIJ7N6ULXg

Comment: If you are here and looking for a window switcher (which is something rofi does "out of the tin" on linux). This question addresses this topic. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240298/switch-between-windows-by-name-on-osx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the [choose](https://github.com/chipsenkbeil/choose) app and it does exactly what you ask for. It takes stdin, shows GUI selector and returns selected item to stdout.

You can install it using `brew install choose-gui`